# Struggling with uppercase or lowercase

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShoutandWhisper {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //defining the variables
        String word, word1;
        //Input
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Give me a word that has 7 letters > ");
        word = kb.nextLine();
        word1 = word.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println("I shout " + word1 + " when I'm excited, but i whisper " + word + " when i can't disturb the neigbours.");
        char achar = word.charAt(0);
        char bchar = word.charAt(1);
        char cchar = word.charAt(2);
        char dchar = word.charAt(3);
        char echar = word.charAt(4);
        char fchar = word.charAt(5);
        char gchar = word.charAt(6);
        //Changing to uppercase
        char Bchar = Character.toUpperCase(bchar);
        char Dchar = Character.toUpperCase(dchar);
        char Fchar = Character.toUpperCase(fchar);
        System.out.println("And the mixed up word is " + achar+Bchar+cchar+Dchar+echar+Fchar+gchar);
    }

}
```

Now the code does work but is there a shorter way to produce alternating Uppercase or Lowercase outputs without using a For counter? rewriting the entire "newer" variables is an accident waiting to happen. Especially with me.

I tried to force it as i was selecting the letter by letter and I couldn't do it.

Main goal is to either Shout or whisper and then sort the word using alternating Uppercases from second letter.

Comment: `"Now the code does work but is there a shorter way to produce alternating Uppercase or Lowercase outputs without using a For counter?"` -- **why not use a for loop?** That would be the most sensible, clean and concise way to solve this, I think. Your current code is very kludgy and prone to breaking, and a for loop would also be much safer.

Comment: Yes I was trying to avoid the For loop, although it seems to be the better way to sort it better and more effectively.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the word to an array of char and use a for loop to alternate upper and lower case :

```
char [] c = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

for(int i = 1; i < c.length; i = i+2){
    c[i] = Character.toUpperCase(c[i]);
}
```

Then just construct a new `String` with this char array (using the constructor [`String(char[] value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29)) and you'll get your word.

Comment: Use `new String(c)` to convert back to a String at the end.

Comment: And don't do `if ( i%2 == 1 ) { ... }`!  Just do `for ( int i=1 ; i < c.length; i = i+2 ) { c[i] = Character.toUppercase( c[i] ); }`.  There's no reason to do `c.length` iterations when you can do `c.length / 2` iterations.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks this is a smarter way.

Comment: Also, to make sure that all chars start at lowerCase, consider `c = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()`

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possibility:

```
public static String scrambleCase(String arg){
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(arg.length());

    for(char ch: arg.toCharArray())
        if(b.length() % 2 == 0) b.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        else b.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));

    return b.toString();
}
```

Comment: And, no, the for loop does not in fact need braces.

Comment: It doesn't *need* them, but the code would be so much clearer, safer and maintainable if it had them.

Comment: Use the `StringBuilder(int capacity)` constructor to ensure that you reserve enough space for the result.

Comment: @JBNizet To me, extra braces is just extra clutter that needs to be processed when I am reading code. It's not a problem if your IDE auto-indents aggresively enough. (It should, in fact, if correctly configured, automatically add braces if you place a line of code at the same indentation as the `if` statement)